# Check if fullscreen by watching document.fullscreenElement in Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I would like to check when the document is in fullscreen. I tried to watch  `document.fullscreen` like that but it does not work :

```js
watch(document.fullscreenElement, (newValue) => {
  fullScreenActivated.value = newValue
})
```

It gives me this :

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid watch source:  null A watch source can only be a getter/effect function, a ref, a reactive object, or an array of these types. 
  at <App> 2 runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:41

[Vue warn]: Invalid watch source:  document.fullscreenElement A watch source can only be a getter/effect function, a ref, a reactive object, or an array of these types. 
  at <App>
```

I understand that you can not watch this element, but I don't know how to do it another way. If somebody has an idea, I will be happy to know about it ! :)

Comment: Listen for fullscreenchange event. You can use premade Vueuse composable that covers common browser apis

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you ! As your answer is a comment, I can not Accept it. Can you put it as an answer please ?

Comment: Sure, glad you solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside Vue, the reactivity is commonly achieved with DOM events. In the case of `fullscreen` property, there's respective [`fullscreenchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fullscreenchange_event) event that allows to track the changes.

Vueuse has composables that wrap common browser APIs this way, including [`useFullscreen`](https://vueuse.org/core/useFullscreen/).